# sql : how to find duplicates rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got a table users (id,first_name,last_name,...)
i want to find duplicate users in that table (users which has the same first_name AND the same last_name).

let's say my data is :

```
 1;bill;campton
 2;sarah;connor
 3;bill;campton
```

i need to get

```
  1;bill;campton;3;bill;campton
```

i dont want to get

```
  1;bill;campton;3;bill;campton
  3;bill;campton;1;bill;campton
```

How could i do that?
I use SQL Server 2005

thank you

Comment: count function is the easy way to find duplicate rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
select u1.id, u2.id, u1.first_name, u1.last_name
from users u1
inner join users u2
on u1.first_name = u2.first_name
and u1.last_name = u2.last_name
where u2.id > u1.id
```

Or, to get your 6 rows, use

```
select u1.id, u1.first_name, u1.last_name, u2.id, u2.first_name, u2.last_name
```

etc.

Answer (score 12):

One way

```
select first_name, last_name
from table
group by first_name, last_name
having count(*) > 1
```

If you want also the IDs then you can do this

```
 SELECT t1.*
 FROM table t1
 join
 (select first_name, last_name
from table
group by first_name, last_name
having count(*) > 1) x ON t1.last_name = x.last_name
AND t1.first_name = x.first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I Just figure this out.  It's very simple. You can use a Common Table Expression and Window partition.

This example finds all students with the same name and DOB.   The fields you want to check for duplication go in the partition.   You could include what ever other fields you want in the projection.

```
with cte (StudentId, Fname, LName, DOB, RowCnt)
as (
SELECT StudentId, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth as DOB, SUM(1) OVER (Partition By FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth) as RowCnt
FROM tblStudent
)
SELECT * from CTE where RowCnt > 1
Order By DOB
```

Comment: I should mention this is SQL Server 2005 or better.

Answer (score 0):

Given the output format you said you wanted, this works:

```
select
  o.id,
  o.firstname,
  o.lastname,
  d.id,
  d.firstname,
  d.lastname
from
  users o
  join users d on d.firstname = o.firstname and d.lastname = o.lastname and o.id < d.id
```

Note that if you have more than one duplicate that you will get results that you probably don't want, and so SQLMenace's solution is probably much better overall.